# foreach laravel total rows differ from count

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h2>{{ $product->name }}</h2>
    <a href="{{action('VarietiesController@create')}}/{{$product->id}}"> Добавить новый вариант </a>
    </br>
    {{$varieties->count()}}
    {{$varieties->first()->name}}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>Название</td>
            <td>Стоимость</td>
            <td>Действие</td>
            <td>Действие</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($varieties as $variety)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$variety->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$variety->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$variety->cost}}</td>
                <td><a href="{{action('VarietiesController@edit', ['VarietyID' => $variety->id])}}">Изменить</a></td>
                <td>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{action('VarietiesController@destroy', ['VarietyID' => $variety->id])}}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Удалить"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    @if(Session::has('message'))
        {{Session::get('message')}}
    @endif
@endsection
```

Expected table with 2 rows but instead I've got table with 0 rows but 
function count is equal 2. What's wrong with that code?

When in controller I've changed

```
'varieties' => Variety::where('product_id','=',3)
```

to

```
'varieties' => Variety::all()
```

That returned what I expected.

RETURN OF FIRST CALL WITH PRODUCT_ID = 3

```
 Американо
     Добавить новый вариант  
     2 Большой 
    id Название Стоимость Действие Действие
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
Variety::where('product_id','=',3)->get();
```

In your case, you just build query, but not fetched the data, to fetch data you should use **get()** method and if you want to fetch all data, you just call **all()** method, read the Laravel docs (:

Comment: @NickSergeev whenever, first you have to read the main docs ) don't forget to mark as solved if I helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `get` function when you use `where`. Change your code to:

`'varieties'=>Variety::where('product_id','=',3)->get();`

Hope this helps.